# CodeIgniter - Store and read Language from database.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am saving language parameters  name like `$lang['list_add']` in a db table as `list_add`. Now I want to store it's value in db for multiple language and retrieve in my CI based app.

How can I access lang files in my app so that they could read and write language values from Db?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll want to create a language file on the fly (e.g. whenever you update the language contents of your  database)

**1st: the database layout**

Create a table `lang_token` with columns `id`, `category`,  `description`, `lang`, `token` and populate its fields like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lang_token` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `category` text NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      `lang` text NOT NULL,
      `token` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

    INSERT INTO `lang_token` (`id`, `category`, `description`, `lang`, `token`) 
    VALUES
      (1, 'list', 'add', 'english', 'add to list'),
      (2, 'list', 'remove', 'english', 'remove from list');
```

**2nd: About CodeIgniter language files**

CodeIgniter will look first in your application/language directory, Each language should be stored in its own folder. Make sure you have your English or German, etc. subdirectories created e.g. `application/language/english`

**3rd: Controller function to create language file on the fly**

About The  Codeigniter language files:
It's a good practice to use a common prefix (category) for all messages in a given file to avoid collisions with similarly named items in other files
There structure is like: `$lang['category_description'] = “token”;`

```
    function updatelangfile($my_lang){
        $this->db2->where('lang',$my_lang);
        $query=$this->db2->get('lang_token');

        $lang=array();
        $langstr="<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
                /**
                *
                * Created:  2014-05-31 by Vickel
                *
                * Description:  ".$my_lang." language file for general views
                *
                */"."\n\n\n";



        foreach ($query->result() as $row){

            $langstr.= "\$lang['".$row->category."_".$row->description."'] = \"$row->token\";"."\n";
        }
        write_file('./application/language/'.$my_lang.'/general_lang.php', $langstr);

    }
```

**Final notes:**

1. Whenever you change your database, you’ll call the function `updatelangfile(‘english’)`
2. Don’t forget to load the *file helper* and *language class* in the constructor of the controller where updatelangfile() is located:

   ```
   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper('file');
       $this->lang->load('general', 'english');
   }
   ```